# Is an injective holomorphic map a topological embedding?

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $M$ and $N$ be complex manifolds and $f \colon M \rightarrow N$ be an injective holomorphic map. Is $f$ necessarily a topological embedding? In other words, is $f$ necessarily a homeomorphism from $M$ onto its image $f(M)$?

In particular, is every immersed submanifold of a complex manifold necessarily an embedded submanifold? An immersed submanifold of a complex manifold $N$ is the image of a complex manifold $M$ under an injective holomorphic immersion $f \colon M \rightarrow N$. An embedded submanifold of a complex manifold $N$ is the image of a complex manifold $M$ under an holomorphic embedding $f \colon M \rightarrow N$ (that is, a holomorphic immersion that is also a topological embedding).

In the context of smooth manifolds, it is well known that the analog questions have a negative answer. I believe that this is still false here, but I have not been able to find any counterexample.

Comment: Of course not. Just think about flat  2-d tori and and immersed flat  submanifolds there.

Comment: Thank you very much Moishe Kohan!

Comment: Choose $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, and consider the map $f \colon \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2}/\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ defined by $f(z) = \left[ (z, \alpha z) \right]$. Then $f$ is an injective holomorphic immersion. However, $f$ is not a topological embedding: By Dirichlet's approximation theorem, there exists a sequence $(q_n)_n$ of positive integers that tends to $+\infty$ such that $dist\left( \alpha q_{n}, \mathbb{Z} \right)$ tends to $0$. Therefore, $f\left( q_{n} \right)$ tends to $\left[ (0, 0) \right] = f(0)$, and hence the inverse of $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Exactly!.......